# Не работает ввод в консоли PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pycharm

Версия PyCharm(Pro):

PyCharm 2017.1.2

Build #PY-171.4249.47, built on April 26, 2017
Licensed to

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.4

При запуске простой программы в PyCharm, выводиться приглашение ввода и при этом чтобы я не печатал на клавиатуре это не отображается в консоли. Но если запустить этот же файл через терминал, то всё работает корректно

Код:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
print(f'Hello, {name}!')
```

Запуск в терминале:

```
MacBook-Air-Daniil:untitled danil$ python3 test.py
What's your name? sad
Hello, sad!
MacBook-Air-Daniil:untitled danil$
```

Запуск в PyCharm

[image: Снимок экрана консоли в PyCharm]

Comment: Возможно ли такое что у вас запущен отладчик?

Comment: Нет, проверял несколько раз это. Почему-то если переписать код под Python 2.7, то ввод работает

Comment: У вас Python 3.6.x ?

Comment: Да, Python 3.6.1

Comment: Попробуйте щёлкнуть ЛКМ по полю ввода после знака вопроса

Comment: @Kit Scibe Банально, но я это уже делал

Comment: @chasie, можно еще указать версию PyCharm с указанием издания (Pro/Community). У меня в старой 5.0.5 pro для Python 3.6.1 приведенный вами код работает - все вводится и выводится без ошибок, и юникод в том числе.

Comment: @m9_psy Добавил информацию о PyCharm в топик и сюда её продублирую ещё, версия PyCharm у меня Pro.
PyCharm 2017.1.2
Build #PY-171.4249.47, built on April 26, 2017
Licensed to danil

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.4